# How can I reduce the file size of PDF files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to reduce the file size of a PDF?

I have couple of things saved in DB as PDF, image, docs, etc. saved as base64, but mostly PDFs and images.

I am able to reduce/scale down images, but would it be possible for PDFs too?

This is for a mobile application. I can compromise on quality (which I am doing with images).

**Edit**

Can't say what's in the pdf, depends on the client, I guess there is no easy/direct way to reduce the size of pdf.

What's your thoughts on compressing the PDF and decompressing at mobile side?  Will it have any effect on reducing the size?

Comment: Try converting the pdf into images page at a time, and cache this, sending the image down to the mobile app

Comment: PDFs contents may or may not already be very condensed. You should analyse your PDFs first.

Comment: I am not sure why this question was down voted. If they could explain, I would be able to ask good question next time.

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on your PDF:

You can remove embedded fonts

You can reduce images quality

You can optimize resources if duplicated (if source is iText it isn't a remote option)